# CakePHP does not insert linking Association for HABTM Relationship

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I have got two Models in CakePHP 2.2.1:

```
class Episode extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tags' => array('className' => 'Tag')
    );
}
```

and

```
class Tag extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Episode' => array('className' => 'Episode')
    );
}
```

And I want to insert an Episode and a Tag at the same time and link them to each other. From the documentation I got that this would be the right code which I execute inside a controller method:

```
$this->Tag->create();
$this->Tag->save(array(
    'name' => 'Test Tag'
));
$tagid = $this->Tag->getInsertID();

var_dump($tagid); // works

$this->Episode->create();
$this->Episode->save(array(
    'Episode' => array(
        'title' => 'Test with Tag'
    ),
    'Tags' => array(
        'Tag' => array($tagid)
    )
));
```

I get no error message and both records are created, but there is no row inserted into the episodes_tags table. CakePHP does these queries:

```
Nr  Query                                                                                                              Err Aff Rws Took (ms)
1   INSERT INTO `pottcast`.`tags` (`name`) VALUES ('Test Tag')                                                              1   1   0
2   INSERT INTO `pottcast`.`episodes` (`title`) VALUES ('Test with Tag')                                                    1   1   0
3   SELECT `EpisodesTag`.`tag_id` FROM `pottcast`.`episodes_tags` AS `EpisodesTag` WHERE `EpisodesTag`.`episode_id` = 9     0   0   0
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

In Episode Model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tag' => array(
        'className' => 'Tag',
        'joinTable' => 'episodes_tags',
        'foreignKey' => 'episode_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',

    ));
```

In your controller:

```
$this->Episode->save(array(
    'Episode' => array(
        'title' => 'Test with Tag'
    ),
    'Tag' => array(
        'Tag' => $tagid
    )
));
```

Ask if not work for you.

Comment: So did I, but nothing changed. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Indeed it does create the row, but I got confused because it prints it as a `SELECT` in the SQL log. Thank you very much for your help! Do you know the reason why there is no third `INSERT`?